# Linker can't find zlib or OpenSSL?

Tags: c, makefile, openssl, zlib

I'm trying to compile shared object using this guidance.
https://github.com/KxSystems/kafka/blob/master/docs/install.md

I'm failing on Step 2 when running "make". I have everything setup accordingly.

```
$ echo $QHOME
/home/h0ax/q
$ echo $KAFKA_ROOT
/usr/include
$ ls  /usr/include | grep librdkafka
librdkafka
```

Here is an error:

```
cc kfk.c -m64 -DKXVER=3 -shared -fPIC -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-parentheses -Wextra -Werror -Wsign-compare -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -L"/usr/include"/lib/ -lrdkafka -lz -lpthread -lssl -g -O2 -I"/usr/include"/include -lrt -o libkfk.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:32: all] Error 1
```

Comment: The thing after `-l` is the library name. So you likely need to install `libz-dev` and `libssh-dev` (or whatever they are called on your Linux distro).

Comment: How did you figure out what libs are exactly required?

Comment: Compiler / linker options of the form `-lfoo` specify that the program depends on functions from a library named `libfoo`, which therefore should be included in the link. `-lz` corresponds to a package named "zlib" (somewhat idiosyncratically), and `-lssl` probably is meant to correspond to the `libssl` provided by OpenSSL.  But that you get such errors strongly suggests that you have not correctly followed the build instructions in the doc you linked, which instructs you to install zlib before building, and to configure the build not to use SSL.

Comment: Oh that's very descriptive. I thought since I followed "Install" part I can skip "Build from source"

Answer (score 0):

Installing this libraries fixed the issue

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I'm using windows subsytem linux with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS